# CSS outline width not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-position, pseudo-element

I am trying to set outline width of the input element on focus.
Outline width stays the same (like it is default setting which can not be changed), no matter of my setting.

[Here is example from code pen](http://codepen.io/FrenkyB/pen/mEaEyL?editors=1100)

And here is part from css where I am trying to set outline-width on focus:

```
input:focus {
  outline-width: 0.1px;
  outline-color: #725b44;  
}
```

**EDIT:**

I've just forgotten to include line style (solid, dotted...).
Now it works. One thing is still strange to me. Why is outline inside element?
Isnt' the outline defined as 'a line that is drawn around elements (outside the borders) to make the element "stand out".'

Here from my example outline looks like this. I thought it's going to be around element, but it's inside:

[image]

Comment: Exactly what would 0.1px look like? Most broswers will either not show it or round it up to 1px.

Comment: What if I want 3px? It doesn't work if I set 3px. Width stays the same.

Comment: Use `outline:1px solid #725b44;`

Comment: Works for me if I put `outline-width: 3px;` Also, easier to use this syntax: `outline: 9px solid blue;`

Answer (score 20):

Add `outline-style: solid` to your css.

Since the default style for the `outline-style` property is `none`, you will have to set it as well (`none|hidden|dotted|dashed|solid|double|groove|ridge|inset|outset|initial|inherit`). Best value you can use for the style is `solid`, but that's a matter of preference.

**Example for the behavior:**

```css
input {
  font-size: 22px;
  padding: 5px 3px;
  color: #666;
}

input.with-outline-style:focus {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #725b44;
  /* You could also use the shorthand: */
  /* outline: 3px solid #666; */
  /*       width style color */
}

input.without-outline-style:focus {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-color: #725b44;
}

body {
  background-color: #fd9;
}

div {
  padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text" class="with-outline-style" value="outline-style set to solid" />
</div>

<div>
  <input type="text" class="without-outline-style" value="outline-style not set" />
</div>
```

**Update**

The `outline-width` setting doesn't work without specifying `outline-style`: if no outline style is set, the browser will render the outline in its default style (which could be anything, such as a dotted rectangle in IE, a shaded rectangle in Chrome, or even nothing).

Comment: Why `outline-width` doesn't work without specifying the outline style?

Comment: Because the default outline style is `none`. If you don't specify the style, the browser will render the outline in its default style (which could be anything, such as a dotted rectangle in IE, a shaded rectangle in Chrome, or even nothing).

Answer (score 2):

Use `outline-style`

```
input:focus {
  outline-width: 0.1px;
  outline-color: #725b44;  
  outline-style: dotted;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
outline: 3px solid #725b44;
```

or

```
outline-width:3px;
outline-color:#725b44;
outline-style:solid;
```

```css
.divMain {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
.divLogin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #CF6B08;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#divLogin {
  background: #FFCC99;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
.spanTitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #003399;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inputFirst {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 30px;
}
.divWarningInputFirst {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 30px;
  top: 88px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #fcdcbb;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.divWarningInputFirst:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 6px;
  border-color: #fcdcbb transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
input:focus {
  outline: 3px solid #725b44;

}
input {
  border-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain" class="divMain">
  
  <div id="divLogin" class="divLogin">
    
    <span id="spanTitle" class="spanTitle">Login</span>
    
    <input type="text" id="inputFirst" class="inputFirst" placeholder="input first">
    
    
    
    <div id="divWarningInputFirst" class="divWarningInputFirst">Please enter input first</div>
    
  </div>
  
  
  
</div>
```

This might help you!

Answer (score 1):

Only if you specify `outline-style` the `outline-width` will take effect. Please check and let me know your feedback. Thanks!

snippet below:

```css
.divMain {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  border: 0px solid black;
}
.divLogin {
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: 5%;
  width: 300px;
  height: 600px;
  border: 1px solid #CF6B08;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
#divLogin {
  background: #FFCC99;
  /* For browsers that do not support gradients */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: linear-gradient(#FAC28A, #FFCC99);
  /* Standard syntax */
}
.spanTitle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #003399;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.inputFirst {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 30px;
}
.divWarningInputFirst {
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 10px);
  height: 30px;
  top: 88px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  border: 0px solid black;
  background-color: #fcdcbb;
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
}
.divWarningInputFirst:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  left: 8px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 0 5px 6px;
  border-color: #fcdcbb transparent;
  display: block;
  width: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
input:focus {
  outline-width: 3px;
  outline-style: solid;
  outline-color: #725b44;
}
input {
  border-color: transparent;
  padding-left: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div id="divMain" class="divMain">

  <div id="divLogin" class="divLogin">

    <span id="spanTitle" class="spanTitle">Login</span>

    <input type="text" id="inputFirst" class="inputFirst" placeholder="input first">



    <div id="divWarningInputFirst" class="divWarningInputFirst">Please enter input first</div>

  </div>



</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `1px` instead of `0.1px` with `outline-style`

```
input:focus {
  outline:1px solid #725b44;  
}
```